# Customizing ASP.NET Identity OWIN pipeline

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity, owin

I'm implementing SSO in ASP.NET MVC 5, .NET 4.8. I am, of course, using `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity` for this, which in turn relies on OWIN middleware.

The OWIN pipeline is set up in `Startup` class, and this is where the relevant SSO identity provider parameters are set (concretely, Azure AD Application parameters). Those parameters need to come from the database, since the application is a multi-tenant solution.

Each request contains a `customerId` in the URL, and I want to use it to determine which parameters to fetch from the database.

`Startup.Auth.cs` looks something like this (unimportant parts omitted for clarity):

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private SSOParameters _parameters;

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use((context, next) =>
        {
            if (_parameters == null)
                // gets customerId from Uri and calls the DB
                _parameters = GetSSOParameters(context.Request.Uri); 
            return next();
        });
        
        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });
            
        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        if (_parameters != null)
        {
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = _parameters.ClientId.ToString(),
                ClientSecret = _parameters.ClientSecret,
                CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-microsoft"),
                MetadataAddress = _parameters.MetadataAddress,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = _parameters.ValidIssuer
                }
            });
        }               
    }
}
```

If I don't place the code that calls the `GetSSOParameters` method in a separate `app.Use` block, the database never gets called. On the other hand, it looks like wrapping it like that introduces some sort of asynchrony between it and the subsequent `app.Whatever` calls, and the `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` never gets the data in time – I always get 401 Unauthorized when attempting to sign in.

It's worth mentioning that this code works with hardcoded values in `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`.

I tried wrapping everything up in a separate `app.Use` as well, but I guess I don't get how OWIN pipeline works.

Does anyone know how I can feed the information gathered in the first `app.Use` to the following `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`?

**[EDIT - another approach/attempt]:**

Well, I tried setting the parameters from the first `app.Use` to the `context` and moving the `app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication` to another `app.Use` in order to access the `context` there as well.

This way my debugger breakpoints actually get triggered (they don't outside `app.Use`) and the data **is there**. But I still get 401 Unauthorized instead of transferring to Microsoft sign in form.

I also replaced `return next()` with `await next.Invoke()`, making the Funcs passed to `Use` async.

The code for this is below:

```
public partial class Startup
{
    private SSOParameters _parameters;

    public void ConfigureAuth(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            if (_parameters == null)
                // gets customerId from Uri and calls the DB
                _parameters = GetSSOParameters(context.Request.Uri);
                
            context.Set("ssoParameters", _parameters);
            await next().Invoke();
        });

        app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
            {
                AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
                LoginPath = new PathString("/Account/Login")
            });

        app.UseExternalSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);

        app.UseTwoFactorSignInCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorCookie, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5));

        app.UseTwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.TwoFactorRememberBrowserCookie);

        app.Use(async (context, next) =>
        {
            var parameters = context.Get<SSOParameters>("ssoParameters");
            app.UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication(new OpenIdConnectAuthenticationOptions
            {
                ClientId = parameters.ClientId.ToString(),
                ClientSecret = parameters.ClientSecret,
                CallbackPath = new PathString("/signin-microsoft"),
                MetadataAddress = parameters.MetadataAddress,
                TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
                {
                    ValidateIssuer = true,
                    ValidIssuer = parameters.ValidIssuer
                }
            });
            
            await next.Invoke();
        }               
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you want custom middleware where you can call Invoke. It executes synchronously but always returns back to the previous middleware piece. Your custom middleware will have to fire prior to the OIDC call.

Comment: @GHDevOps Abd you think I'll then be able to access the `private SSOParameters _parameters` global variable from `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`? I've tried adding it to Owin Context, and I actually manage to get it in `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`, but I still recieve 401 Unauthorized.

Comment: I've done it with IOptions and json but not with a db call. Should be very similar. Look into IOptions and use that wrapper to pass in as a parameter between your middleware.

Comment: @GHDevOps Ah, the problem is that I'm actually **not** passing a parameters between two middlewares. I'm trying to pass a parameter which I'm setting into one of them into the other  from the `ConfigureAuth` method. I suspect that, middlewares being async, this parameter doesn't get set in time to reach the other one(`UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`).